# Spying on Jasmine-Jquery function calls

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

The following jasmine-jquery snippet fails.  The error I get is "Expected spy logIt to have been called".

```
var logIt = function () { 
    console.log("logged"); 
};

$('#id1').on({
    click: logIt
});

describe("Clicking id1", function() {
  it("logs to the console.", function() {
      spyOn(window, 'logIt');
      $('#id1').click();
      expect(window.logIt).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});

//ERROR: "Expected spy logIt to have been called."
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
describe("Clicking id1", function() {
    var logIt, $button;

    beforeAll(function () {
        logIt = jasmine.createSpy('logIt() spy');

        $button = $('#id1');
        $button.click(logIt);
        $button.click();
    });

    it("logs to the console.", function () {
        expect(logIt).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I ran the test below in my project and it worked:

```
describe("Clicking id1", function() {
    var $button, specHelper, logIt;

    beforeAll(function () {
        logIt = jasmine.createSpy('logIt() spy');
        $button = $('<button>').attr("id", "id1");
        specHelper = new SpecHelper();
        specHelper.publish($button);

        $button.click(logIt);
        $button.click();
    });

    afterAll(function () {
        specHelper.conceal($button);
    });

    it("logs to the console.", function () {
        console.dir(logIt);
        expect(logIt).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

`specHelper.publish` appends the jQuery node to the DOM and `specHelper.conceal` removes it.

Comment: This generates the same comment.

Comment: I tested the an adapted version of the above code and it worked for me... do you have an html element with `id="id1"` on your jasmine-html-page? If not, this will cause the comment.

Comment: OK -- yours works once I added the element with "id1".  But even adding the element, my original test which uses `spyOn` fails.  Do you know why that is?

Comment: i don't know it exactly. i know, that jasmine builds a tree with all jasmine-functions (`describe`, `it`, ...) before executing the tests -> so you will have problems, to create "global" functions and objects.... Just structure all your specs like above. then you won't have any problems ;-)